# Array and Function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, program-entry-point

I am trying to make functions to call in the main function, trying to keep "main" as clean as possible.
so I made a function to get the size array from the user then the user enters the elements of the function, but I got stuck at the linear search function, so want help "Still absolute beginner"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* Array_Elements () {
    static int arr [5] {}, i, size;
    cout << "Enter Array size: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter Array Elements: " << endl;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
void Array_Search (int arr [], int n) {
    int temp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (arr [i] == n) {
            cout << "Element found at position: " << i + 1 << endl;
            temp = 0;
            break;
        }
 }
 
  if (temp == -1) {
    cout << "No Element Found" << endl;
  }    
    }
int num () {
    cout << "Please enter an element to search" << endl;
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    return num;
}

int main () {
    Array_Search (Array_Elements(), num());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on "I got stuck". What is the problem?

Comment: *trying to keep "main" as clean as possible.* This is sound ideology.

Comment: I have seen `static int arr [5] {}` before as a workaround to passing arrays around. This is a "trick", and not a good one. Use `std::array` and pass it between functions instead of using a global `int arr[5]`

Comment: Wait. I've totally misread the purpose of the code. Gol durn it. Sometimes you can be too terse and the results can be disasterous.

Comment: OK. Now that I'm on page, refrain from making a search function that does anything with the found item. This results in a search function that can only be used for one thing. So when you have another use for the search function, you have to write another search function. Instead, `Array_Search` should return the location or -1 and have another function, or an `if` statement in `main`, because there's such a thing as breaking down things too much, that uses the result.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`? Always using an array of 5 `int`s seems kind of silly if the user could say they want , say, six or more items in the array.

Comment: You have declared the array capacity as 5.  You then ask the User for the quantity of elements.  What happens when the User enters the quantity as 10?  13? 257?  Don't use arrays; use `std::vector` because `std::vector` can expand during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets jump right in, my suggestion to keep the main as clean as possible is to use a class then instantiate its object then use the object to call class methods in the main. This is best practice.

Your code confuses the compiler, in that the function num() precedes the function Array_Elements() in terms of order of evaluation. And I believe you want it the other way around.

Here's how to fix it: Remove the function num(), and make the following changes to your code

```
int* Array_Elements(int size) {
    int* arr, i;
    cout << "Enter Array Elements: " << endl;
    arr = new int[size];
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}

void Array_Search (int *arr, int size) { 
    int temp = -1, num;
    cout << "Please enter an element to search" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr [i] == num) {
            cout << "Element found at position: " << i + 1 << endl;
            temp = 0;
            delete [] arr;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (temp == -1) {
    cout << "No Element Found" << endl;
    }    
}

int main () {
    int size;
    cout << "Enter Array size: ";
    cin >> size;
    Array_Search(Array_Elements(size),size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I do the above code without a pointer...?!

Comment: If you want the array to be dynamic use pointers, without a pointer the array will be static, so it will have a constant size.

Comment: you are leaking the memory

Comment: Okay, where is the memory leak...?!

Answer (score 1):

> ... trying to keep "main" as clean as possible.

Ok, thats a good motivation. Frankly, I find your `main` rather confusing. You try to do 3 seperate steps in one line and probably tripped over unspecified evalutation order of the function parameters. I have to admit, I don't remember if or in what version of C++ the order of evaluation of function parameters is specified. And I suggest you to not even try to remember it. Instead write code that does seperate steps in seperate steps.

Your `main` could look like this:

```
int main() {
    auto arr = Array_Elements();
    int number = num();
    Array_Search(arr,number);
}
```

Even without a definition of `Array_Elements()`, `num()` or `Array_Searcher` one can get a rough idea of the three steps made here.

---

Next, global state is not clean. Your `Array_Elements ()` cannot reasonably be called twice:

```
int* first_array = Array_Element();
int* second_array = Array_Element();
```

Both pointers would point to the same `arr`. The second call to `Array_Element` will overwrite what the first call assigned.

`static int arr [5] {}` as workaround to passing arrays around is a hack. It isn't the right way to solve that problem. Sloppy speaking it isn't any cleaner than a sphagetti `main`.

---

Use `std::array` when you want a stack allocated array with size known at compile time and `std::vector` for dynamic arrays. They can be passed between functions and you need not keep track of the size seperate from the array:

```
std::vector<int> Array_Elements() {
    std::cout << "Enter Array size: ";
    unsigned size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> result(size);
    std::cout <<  "Enter Array Elements: \n";
    for (auto& element : result){
        std::cin >> element;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The loop is a [range based for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). In a nutshell, it iterates all elements in `result` and `element` is a reference to the elements.

---

Get acustomed to standard algorithms. They aren't doing something that you could not write yourself. Though, they help to write cleaner code, because instead of having several lines of code that all deal with one thing, "find an element", we can have one function call with a meaningful name: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
void Array_Search(const std::vector<int>& arr,int n){
    auto it = std::find(arr.begin(),arr.end(),n);
    if (it == arr.end()) {
        std::cout << "No Element Found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Element found at position: " << (it - arr.begin()) << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

In case the element was not found it returns the end iterator. When it does find the element we can calculate the index from an iterator by subtracting the begin iterator.

---

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a3WWzf)

Comment: To this I'd add a helper function to read `int`s from the user, perform sanity checks on the input and clean up after the user's typos or hacking attempts. Then I'd use this function in place of all `cin >> some_int;`s in the code.

Comment: @user4581301 now I remember what I forgot to mention, thanks

Comment: No, thank you. Saved me time. I didn't have to finish writing my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, but the professor asked not to contain vectors, methods, objects, or algorithm I should write it on my own...